# articles like "the" carrying over using conjunction reduction

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conjunction-reduction

> Jon had used the scientific approach of his brother and artistic approach of his sister.

Would definite article "the" be implicit before "artistic" due to conjunction reduction? Since the phrase before "and" is long, the lack of "the" before artistic may initially appear to have the potential to sound incorrect.

Comment: The definite article can be and often is elided in this way. But speaking personally I would include it a second time. The sentence just sounds more complete.

Comment: I think it sounds more awkward to leave it out when the phrases are several words long like this.

Comment: @Barmar: It's a fine point where you draw the line. I don't mind OP's version particularly, but I couldn't really go for it in *"Jon used the scientific approach of his brother Michael famed for his contributions to gamma-ray astronomy, and artistic approach of his sister"*. Which sister would probably have to be expanded upon too anyway, but that's irrelevant. The point is that at some point the distance between the *actual* "the" and the [deleted/elided] one just becomes too great.

Comment: Please pass me the box I put on the table and can you put on the worktop.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That example has two problems: the distance from _the_ to the second phrase, and ambiguity between _can_ as a verb or noun. I can't help parsing _can you put_ as the beginning of a question, then I have to back up when the object is missing. It took me 3 tries to figure out what was meant.

Comment: @Barmar. I couldn't manage three; I've just been to a family gathering.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I just realized that the second phrase could be parsed on its own if _worktop_ were an article of clothing, then _put on_ would be related to wearing it.

Comment: Please pass me the box I put on the table and can you put on the stove.

Comment: Seems fine to me. It is a pretty simple structure and there is the related concept of one approach for brother and one for sister. Upon first reading it seems not ambiguous. It is not ambiguous until folks start looking at it with a microscope. Also, presumably it would be uttered in a context that helped or confirmed the speaker/writer's meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Or, putting it another way, the direct object of this sentence is a noun phrase with article "the" in construction with a compound noun which is the coordinate conjunction of the two nouns "scientific approach of his brother" and "artistic approach of his sister".  (Generally, a conjunction of two phrases has the same category as each of the conjoined phrases.  Here, some grammarians might use the category N-bar where I have used just N.)